# Importing data from text

Tags: java, string, text, input

I have a bunch of text files with entries that look like this:

```
20662 = {
    name="Durgulel"
    dynasty=100603
    martial=7
    diplomacy=4
    intrigue=5
    stewardship=4
    learning=6
    religion="orthodox"
    culture="alan"
    trait="chaste"
    trait="arbitrary"
    trait="scholarly_theologian"
    father=41592
    992.1.1={
        birth="992.1.1"
    }
    1068.1.1={
        death="1068.1.1"
    }
}
```

Is there a standard way for reading values from something like this into variables?

Comment: `Is there a standard way for reading values`. Which values do you want to read... the values in the "quotes"?

Comment: try substituting = with : and it looks like JSON. Some JSON parser may be able to process it, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a StreamTokenizer; should look roughly like this (untested):

```
static Map<String,Object> parse(
     StreamTokenizer tokenizer, int endToken) throws IOException {
  Map<String,Object> result = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
  while (tokenizer.nextToken() != endToken) {
    String key = tokenizer.sval;
    if (tokenizer.nextToken() != '=') {
      throw new RuntimeException("'=' expected");
    }
    if (tokenizer.nextToken() == '{') {
      result.put(key, parse(tokenizer, '}'));
    } else {
      tokenizer.nextToken();
      result.put(key, tokenizer.sval);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Reader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
  Map<String,Object> parsed = parse(
     new StreamTokenizer(reader), StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF);
  System.out.println(parsed);
}
```

p.s. This will need some additional handling for 922.1.1 and similar keys. If the format is really just line based, it might be more straight forward to use BufferedReader.readLine(), trim() and check for { / } / =

p.p.s If by variables you mean instance member variables, you could use the Java reflection API to set them accordingly (instead of reading to a map as in the example). You'd hand in the object to fill and then look up and set the members via object.getClass().getField(key).set(object, value)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways to read files into a program. I'd recommend reading about `BufferedReader`, `FileReader`, and `Scanner`. Some documentation on the following:

[FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

[BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

I usually pair `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` because the `BuffereReader` method `nextLine()` is conveniant for string variables. It's implemented as follows:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String x = br.readLine();
```

I'd also recommend some sort of regex expression for reading in your lines because of how the document is formatted. An example of an way of reading in seperate words into indices of a `String[]` with `readLIne()` and a simple regex expression is: `String wH[] = br.readLine().split("\\W+");` This might be useful for splitting each line based on its contents, but since your lines don't appear to be separated by spaces, it always viable to just examine the raw string based in by `readLine()` in some sort of `for-loop`.

Once you've targeted the exact values you want, you can assign them to variables. For example, lets say you have a condition that detects the phrase "name" in a line, you could then assign the value that comes after the `=` and between the quotes to your desired variable. Then Rinse and Repeat.

Hope this helps.